# Flutter if statement in a custom class

Tags: android, flutter, class, flutter-layout

I have a class like this:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class myTextStyle extends TextStyle {
  final Color color;
  final double size;
  final String fontFamily;
  final bool bold;

  const myTextStyle({
    required this.size,
    this.color = Colors.black87,
    this.fontFamily = 'OpenSans',
  })
      : assert(size != null),
        super(
        color: color,
        fontSize: size,
        fontFamily: fontFamily,
      );
}
```

I want to add a if statement for bold. İf bold==true a want to make Fontweigh=Fontweight.bold. Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.FontWeight = bold ? FontWeight.bold : FontWeight.normal
```

I belive this is what you are looking for.
It is called ternary operator.

```
class myTextStyle extends TextStyle {
  final Color color;
  final double size;
  final String fontFamily;
  final FontWeight fontWeight;  
  const myTextStyle({
    @required this.size,
    this.color = Colors.black87,
    this.fontFamily = 'OpenSans',
    this.fontWeight = FontWeight.normal,
  })  : assert(size != null),
        super(
          color: color,
          fontSize: size,
          fontFamily: fontFamily,
          fontWeight: fontWeight
        );
}
```

I think you should do it like that and then in your widget when you call your `myTextStyle` use this ternary operator.

> The const keyword is used when the value of the variable is known at compile-time and never changes. In other words, the compiler knows in advance what value is to be stored in that variable. const int x = 1;//At compile time, the value of x is going to be 1 and will not change

so since myTextStyle is const you cannot use dynamic values there because at compile time you dont have it yet.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I implemented this but now say "The default value of an optional parameter must be constant.". Can you help me?

Comment: @ŞahinYakıcı up. This could be useful to understand why https://medium.com/flutter-community/the-flutter-const-keyword-demystified-c8d2a2609a80

Comment: @ŞahinYakıcı np, we all learn